# Deleting local file through UITableView causing out of bounds array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a UITableView on a view controller which has been set up where it displays all files that have been downloaded into the documents of the application. So I decided to add the ability to delete files through the same table view. What happens is that the file actually deletes but crashes afterwards. The debugger states: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

Here is my code for the delete button as well:

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSString *currentFileName = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFileName];


    [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];


}
}
```

Code for table view:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [filePathsArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
}
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
cell.textLabel.text = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];


return cell;
}
```

So what is causing the variable to exceed? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please check if the `NSFileManager `'s `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` method is executed successfully (pass `&error` instead of `nil` for the last argument and check `error` for nil after call of this method). 
If the `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` method is called without errors (i.e. if `error` is `nil`) then the information you've supplied in your question is not enough for me for the further analysis. I'd like to see implementation of your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods.

Comment: I done what you said and the same error is still being outputted by the debugger

Comment: @NikolayMamaev thats all the details added now that you asked for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out! I forgot to remove the object from the array and reload the tableview, here is the working code for anyone wanting to do the same:

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSString *currentFileName = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFileName];

   NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];

    [filePathsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData];




}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this happens when you delete a file, I'm assuming you're testing this using only one file. Meaning the problem most likely occurs when you do this:

```
[paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

you should do something like check if paths (or any array you access from now on) is null before you attempt to access it. So that would look like this:

```
if(paths == nil || [paths count] == 0){
//handle the exception by not looking in paths, maybe logging something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, assuming that `filePathsArray` is an instance variable, it's not clear for me why you re-initialize it for each call of your delegate methods. From my point of view, it just doesn't make sense. You either always (in all methods including `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`) use `NSFileManager`'s `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` and don't use `filePathsArray` at all, or cache results of `NSFileManager`'s `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` in the `filePathsArray` and update this ivar only when delete a file.

Regarding your exception, I believe its root cause is as follows:
In your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method, you re-initialize `filePathsArray` in improper place. You should do it **after** deletion of the file. In the sample below, I write your current code without taking into account my comment above about `filePathsArray` (i.e. I use your current code without any fixes for this comment).

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSError *error;
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
        NSString *currentFileName = [filePathsArray[indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
        NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFileName];


        [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];

        filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately what you recommended did not work for me